# Automatic and dynamic line-break of subviews with AutoLayout (>iOS 6)

Tags: ios, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

I would like subviews to align horizontally inside their superview (with a fixed width) and **automatically 'line-break'** when the trailing edge of the superview is reached. 
I am looking for a solution that empowers Auto Layout to do the whole work for me - **without** (re-)calculating the row structure when a subview's size changes dynamically (like a text field that grows/shrinks with its content for example) and **adding or removing constraints**.

I already have a (working) solution, that (re-)creates constraints according to a pre-(and re-)calculated row-structure of the subviews.

**So all my question is about is: can there be found a  solution that uses constraints in such a constellation (with flexibilities, priorities a.s.o.), that empowers Auto Layout to automatically do the line-break on a subview if needed (on first load AND on runtime).**

I've created an example project with `UILabels` as 'subviews'. Please, play around with this - or try to convince me, that my idea is simply visionary - but not realisable at the moment.

Actual Screenshot for the code below:

[image: labels drawn above each other according to priorities set in addConstraintsForLabels:superview: method]

**This is the method that tests the dynamic new line Auto Layout:**

```
- (void) addConstraintsForLabels : (NSArray*) labels
                   superview : (UIView*) superview {

    for (int i = 0; i < labels.count; i++) {
        UILabel* precedingLabel = i == 0 ? nil : labels[i - 1];
        UILabel* label = labels[i];
        [label setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints: NO];

        //// set all contentHuggingPriorities to no growing and no compression
        [label setContentHuggingPriority: UILayoutPriorityRequired forAxis: UILayoutConstraintAxisHorizontal];
        [label setContentHuggingPriority: UILayoutPriorityRequired forAxis: UILayoutConstraintAxisVertical];
        [label setContentCompressionResistancePriority: UILayoutPriorityRequired forAxis: UILayoutConstraintAxisHorizontal];
        [label setContentCompressionResistancePriority: UILayoutPriorityRequired forAxis: UILayoutConstraintAxisVertical];

        //// constraints affecting superview
        // top to superview
        NSLayoutConstraint* topToSup =  [NSLayoutConstraint alignEdge: NSLayoutAttributeTop                                                      ofViews: @[label, superview]                                                           relation: i == 0 ? NSLayoutRelationEqual : NSLayoutRelationGreaterThanOrEqual
                                                          spacing: 0];
        // leading to superview
        NSLayoutConstraint* leadingToSup = [NSLayoutConstraint alignEdge: NSLayoutAttributeLeading
                                                             ofViews: @[label, superview]
                                                            relation: i == 0 ? NSLayoutRelationEqual : NSLayoutRelationGreaterThanOrEqual
                                                             spacing: 0];
        // bottom to superview
        NSLayoutConstraint* bottomToSup = [NSLayoutConstraint alignEdge: NSLayoutAttributeBottom
                                                            ofViews: @[label, superview]
                                                           relation: i == labels.count - 1 ? NSLayoutRelationEqual : NSLayoutRelationLessThanOrEqual
                                                            spacing: 0];
        // trailing to superview
        NSLayoutConstraint* trailingToSup = [NSLayoutConstraint alignEdge: NSLayoutAttributeTrailing
                                                              ofViews: @[label, superview]
                                                             relation: NSLayoutRelationLessThanOrEqual
                                                              spacing: 0];

        //// example constraints affecting preceding label
        // leading to preceding label
        NSLayoutConstraint* leadingToPrec = precedingLabel == nil ? nil : [NSLayoutConstraint horizontalSpacing: 0
                                                                                               betweenViews: @[precedingLabel, label]
                                                                                                   flexible: NO
                                                                                                  inMaximum: NO];
        // y position to preceding label
        NSLayoutConstraint* centerYToPrec = precedingLabel == nil ? nil :  [NSLayoutConstraint alignEdge: NSLayoutAttributeCenterY
                                                                                             ofViews: @[label, precedingLabel]
                                                                                            relation: NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                                             spacing: 0];
        // top to preceding view
        NSLayoutConstraint* topToPrec = precedingLabel ==  nil ? nil : [NSLayoutConstraint verticalSpacing: 0
                                                                                               ofViews: @[precedingLabel, label]
                                                                                              flexible: NO
                                                                                             inMaximum: NO];

        //// priorities
        // affecting the superview
        topToSup.priority = UILayoutPriorityRequired; // is either flexible or non-flexible for the first
        leadingToSup.priority = UILayoutPriorityRequired; // is either flexible or non-flexible for the first
        bottomToSup.priority = UILayoutPriorityRequired; // is either flexible or non-flexible for the last
        trailingToSup.priority = UILayoutPriorityRequired; // it is required, that the view does not exceed the right edge of its superview
        [superview addConstraints: @[trailingToSup, topToSup, leadingToSup, bottomToSup]];

        // affecting the preceding view
        if (i > 0) {
            leadingToPrec.priority = UILayoutPriorityDefaultHigh;
            centerYToPrec.priority = UILayoutPriorityDefaultHigh;
            topToPrec.priority = UILayoutPriorityDefaultHigh;
            [superview addConstraints: @[leadingToPrec, centerYToPrec, topToPrec]];
        }
    }
}
```

The imported category that extends `NSLayoutConstraint`:

```
@implementation NSLayoutConstraint (ConstructorAdditions)


// align edges of two views
// if one view is the superview, put it at the second position in the array
+ (NSLayoutConstraint*) alignEdge : (NSLayoutAttribute) edge
                      ofViews : (NSArray*) /*UIView*/ views
                     relation : (NSLayoutRelation) relation
                      spacing : (CGFloat) spacing {
    NSLayoutConstraint* constraint = nil;
    if (views.count == 2) {
        if (edge == NSLayoutAttributeBaseline || edge == NSLayoutAttributeTrailing || edge == NSLayoutAttributeBottom || edge == NSLayoutAttributeRight) {
            spacing = -spacing;
        }
        constraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem : [views objectAtIndex: 0]
                                              attribute : edge
                                              relatedBy : relation
                                                 toItem : [views objectAtIndex: 1]
                                              attribute : edge
                                             multiplier : 1.0
                                               constant : spacing];
    }
    return constraint;
}


// vertical spcacing between views
// the method assumes, that the first view in the array is above the second view
+ (NSLayoutConstraint*) verticalSpacing : (CGFloat) spacing
                            ofViews : (NSArray*) /*UIView*/ views
                           flexible : (BOOL) flexible
                           inMaximum: (BOOL) inMax {
    NSLayoutConstraint* constraint = nil;

    NSLayoutRelation relation = flexible ? (inMax ? NSLayoutRelationLessThanOrEqual : NSLayoutRelationGreaterThanOrEqual) : NSLayoutRelationEqual;

    if (views.count == 2) {
        constraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem : [views objectAtIndex: 0]
                                              attribute : NSLayoutAttributeBottom
                                              relatedBy : relation
                                                 toItem : [views objectAtIndex: 1]
                                              attribute : NSLayoutAttributeTop
                                             multiplier : 1.0
                                               constant : -spacing];
    }
    return constraint;
}


// horizontal spacing between views
// the method assumes, that the first view in the array is left of the second view
+ (NSLayoutConstraint*) horizontalSpacing : (CGFloat) spacing
                         betweenViews : (NSArray*) /*UIView*/ views
                             flexible : (BOOL) flexible
                             inMaximum: (BOOL) inMax {
    NSLayoutConstraint* constraint = nil;
    NSLayoutRelation relation = flexible ? (inMax ? NSLayoutRelationLessThanOrEqual : NSLayoutRelationGreaterThanOrEqual) : NSLayoutRelationEqual;
    if (views.count == 2) {
        constraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem : [views objectAtIndex: 0]
                                              attribute : NSLayoutAttributeTrailing
                                              relatedBy : relation
                                                 toItem : [views objectAtIndex: 1]
                                              attribute : NSLayoutAttributeLeading
                                             multiplier : 1.0
                                               constant : -spacing];
    }
    return constraint;
}



+ (NSArray*) equalWidthOfViews : (NSArray*) views
                    toView : (UIView*) view
                  distance : (CGFloat) distance
                  relation : (NSLayoutRelation) relation
                multiplier : (CGFloat) multiplier {
    NSMutableArray* constraints = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity: views.count];

    for (UIView* aView in views) {
        [constraints addObject: [NSLayoutConstraint  constraintWithItem : aView
                                                          attribute : NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                                                          relatedBy : relation
                                                             toItem : view
                                                          attribute : NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                                                         multiplier : multiplier
                                                           constant : distance]];
    }
    return constraints;
}
```

Comment: Please reduce your provided code to the parts that contain your problem. You should find out for yourself, what invokes the error instead of delegating this to the community!

Comment: I neither have an error problem, nor do I not know where the screenshot result above is coming from. But nevertheless, I will reduce the code a bit for better clarity. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is a pretty demanding task for Autolayout. The solve time for constraints increases exponentially as you add more and more constraints. It looks like UICollectionView might fit your needs better. It is already very optimized for doing something like this, specifically the UICollectionViewFlowLayout layout.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So my question about `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` is: will the `UICollectionView` be able to handle a `UICollectionViewCell` that contains a growing `UITextField`? I mean, does the `UICollectionView` work with such dynamic cells or do I have to reload the `UICollectionView` each time the user changes one character of the textField because of its size change?

Comment: Good question! CollectionView is capable of reloading just one cell for starters. Layouts are also capable of invalidating layout attributes only for individual cells (iOS 8 makes this easier, but it's possible in iOS 7 too I think). This might be your best approach though I haven't much experience with doing that though.

Comment: Another "trick" you might need to employ is to pluck the TextView out of the cell right as it becomes the first responder. As the user types, determine the width for the cell, invalidate the layout (or reload) the cell, but also update the textField's frame to "follow" the cell. That way you don't risk losing first responder on that text view if the cell does need to reload. With invalidating the layout attributes this might not be necessary, but firstResponder can be a fickle beast.